# Can't upload APK file on Play Console, asks for AAB File extenesion

Tags: file-upload, apk, google-play-console, apk-expansion-files, android-app-bundle

Trying to upload my compiled Python Kivy application (APK) on Play Console. An error pop ups with "Invalid file type" (Asks for .AAB File Extension). Could you please help me out with this issue? And if no way to upload APK, how to convert APK to AAB.

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

Since August 1 2021, all new apps uploaded to Google play store are required to be in the aab format. this is Google's official announcement :
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html?m=1

You can't convert an apk into an Aab. They use different compilation paths, but here is a temporal workaround to create an Aab using Android Studio:
https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#how-to-create-a-release-bundle-aab